# Is there a way to make expiration time on GeneratePresignedUrlRequest working properly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I have been trying to set a expiration time once I send a request to AWS in order to create a Pre-signed URL; However, I don't get the Pre-signed URL expired as the time I need.

Here is some code I use from AWS:

```java
 java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
            long expTimeMillis = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
            expTimeMillis += 1000;
            System.out.println("expired Time:"+expTimeMillis);
            expiration.setTime(expTimeMillis);
            GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, key)
                    .withMethod(HttpMethod.GET).withExpiration(expiration);
    URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
```

After sending that request to AWS, I got this pre-signed URL:

```
https://BucketName.amazonaws.com/ABC/DEF/ABC.csv
    ?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%20ABC.csv%22
    &X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20221005T024318Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
    &X-Amz-Expires=0&X-Amz-Credential=AASDus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request
    &X-Amz-Signature=HHHHH
```

I was able to download the file and able to use that presigned URL after 5 minutes also.
However, after 10 minutes or so, I got this message. If I am not missing anything, I expected to get this message after 1 second instead of after 10 minutes.

```xml
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Request has expired</Message>
<X-Amz-Expires>0</X-Amz-Expires>
<Expires>2022-10-05T02:43:18Z</Expires>
<ServerTime>2022-10-05T02:45:01Z</ServerTime>
<RequestId>RequestID</RequestId>
<HostId>Host</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: Perhaps your browser is caching the result? What happens if you generate the pre-signed URL and then wait 2 minutes before using the URL -- does it return the object?

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein. I have tried your advice by waiting 2 minutes and using different browsers and private window or incognito window. The issue was still there( it still return the object) 
For security reasons, I set expiration time is 2-5 seconds instead of minutes

Comment: It might be due to clock drift on your computer -- is it set automatically from a Time Server? Sometimes people create pre-signed URLs using the wrong timezone (AWS uses UTC), but that doesn't seem to be the situation for you since the URL stops after a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein. i was using a wrong timezone. After trying your advice, I was able to solve the issue. My bad of being late in response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be due to clock drift on your computer -- check that it is set automatically from a Time Server.

Sometimes people create pre-signed URLs using the wrong timezone (AWS uses UTC), so confirm that the time used in the URL is in UTC.

Comment: Thanks @John Rotenstein. After review timezone based on your advice, I was able to set expiration time as I need.